# How to force PulseAudio to recognize my audio device

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, usb-audio

I have a Lenovo laptop.  For about two years my Focusrite Saffire audio interface has worked correctly and shown up in the "Output" options of the Sound Settings.

Now, it not randomly started to now show up as an Output device.

Unplugging and plugging it back in occasionally works (gets it to appear as an output option and starts playing) but not all the time. Sometimes it doesn't appear, even when it is visible to `aplay -l`.

Here is an example:

`aplay -l` outputs `card 2: USB [Scarlett 2i4 USB], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]` (the card I want to use) but it does not show up in "Sound" (which I think is pulseaudio). How can I get it to show up when the OS obviously sees it and it used to work?

[image]

Comment: Please click [edit] and advise the model number from the serial number plate underneath. "Thinkpad 999' or 'Idapad 666' isn't adequate to find what we need to solve this.

Comment: @K7AAY updated.

Comment: Please click [edit] and advise the model number from the serial number plate underneath. "Thunkpad 999' or 'Idapad 666' isn't adequate to find what we need to solve this. Also, please advise which distro and version of Linux is in use.